# how to find pigeon holes in a question related to pigeon hole principle

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

prove that every set of 10 two digit numbers has two disjoint subsets with the same sum of elements.

In this question i don't know how to choose the pigeon holes, or what will be the pigeon holes

Comment: Hint:  first verify the claim without the condition that the sets be disjoint (that's straight pigeonhole).  Then argue that you can produce disjoint examples out of non-disjoint ones.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the better "pigeon hole" problems are quite subtle and it is not trivial to figure out how the principle will be used.

In this case, think of all the different sums you can create. (How many subsets, of all possible cardinalities, does a set with 10 elements have?) Those are the pigeons.

On the other hand, the sums are at most 1,000 (ten numbers, all two digits at most). These are the holes.

The pigeon hole principle, after you do the count in the second paragraph, will tell you that two of those sums, for two different subsets, must be equal. This doesn't give you DISJOINT subsets, but you can simply cancel out the common terms.